# Notification for checkov scan

Tags: shell, terraform, yaml, devsecops, checkov

I have a makefile and a checkov config file in terraform/eks folder. Makefile is written in bash shell script and config file is written in yaml file. I want to add notification such that whenever build fails due to checkov scan fails, then the team should get notification.
Is there any way to add notification in either of the file.

Inside the Makefile I have this line:

```
checkov: tf_plan_as_json ##Testing run checkov validation against terraform plan file
$(info Executing Checkov)
$(Checkov) -f $(DOCKER_WORKING_DIR)/$(TF_MODULE_PATH)/tfplan.json --config-file $(CHECKOV_CONFIG)
```

Can anyone pls help me understand what is written over here and can we had a line which will send me a notification if this Checkov scan fails?

Comment: Include a [mcve] so readers can help inprove your understanding. (I didn't downvote). Good luck.

Comment: I have updated the description with some code details. Hope it helps others and me finding an answer to the same.

Comment: *"Makefile is written in bash shell script"* `Makefile`s have a different syntax than shell scripts. Or are you using `cmake`? (which I know nothing about). It should be the case that if any error occurs in your `make` process, it should exit with a non-zero exit code. So you could make a wrapper script like `if make -f /path/to/makeFile ; then echo No error ; else mail -s "error in makefile" userlist ; fi` Given your lack of details that is probably all that anyone can offer to help. Else make a better, **small** example. All it needs is to fail, and then you report the error as in my sample.

Comment: Thanks @shellter this should help, I will try to make some changes and see to it.